# How can I install a Haskell library to be accessible via GHCi with Nixos?

Tags: haskell, nix, nixos

I've managed to install ghc with `nix-env -i ghc`.

I'd like to install a Haskell library now, how should this be done? For example the `turtle` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle) library.

I've run `nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -iA haskellPackages.turtle`, however running `ghci` and `import Turtle` fails:

```
Prelude> import Turtle

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Turtle’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

Output of `ghc-pkg list`:

```
/nix/store/fvf278s3lqsjv488ahhdi8jx6i0qzsr9-ghc-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/package.conf.d      
Cabal-1.24.2.0                          
array-0.5.1.1                           
base-4.9.1.0                            
binary-0.8.3.0                          
bytestring-0.10.8.1                     
containers-0.5.7.1                      
deepseq-1.4.2.0                         
directory-1.3.0.0                       
filepath-1.4.1.1                        
ghc-8.0.2                               
ghc-boot-8.0.2                          
ghc-boot-th-8.0.2                       
ghc-prim-0.5.0.0                        
ghci-8.0.2                              
haskeline-0.7.3.0                       
hoopl-3.10.2.1                          
hpc-0.6.0.3                             
integer-gmp-1.0.0.1                     
pretty-1.1.3.3                          
process-1.4.3.0                         
rts-1.0                                 
template-haskell-2.11.1.0               
terminfo-0.4.0.2                        
time-1.6.0.1                            
transformers-0.5.2.0                    
unix-2.7.2.1                            
xhtml-3000.2.1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works differently on NixOS because of purity. NixOS' GHC will only look at its own immutable installation directory and the packages that have been installed by the user with `cabal install`.

What you can do is install into your user profile a GHC wrapper that supplies a nice set of packages when you run `ghci`.

Create a file `my-ghc.nix`:

```
(import <nixpkgs> {}).haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (hpkgs: with hpkgs; [
    lens
    aeson
    turtle
])
```

Uninstall your previous attempt, to avoid name collisions:

```
nix-env -e ghc turtle
```

Install the wrapped GHC:

```
nix-env -if my-ghc.nix
```

You may edit the file in the future and re-run that command.

When I am working on a project, I prefer to use `cabal2nix` and `nix-shell`. (For an introduction, see [Oliver Charles' blog post](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-02-04-how-i-develop-with-nixos.html))

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative Robert's answer, one can use a `nix-shell` environment by creating a `shell.nix` file with contents of:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let myGhc = pkgs.haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (hpkgs: with hpkgs; [
      turtle
    ]);
in
pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [ myGhc ];
}
```

And entering this environment with `nix-shell`.

Alternatively this single command `nix-shell -p "haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (pkgs: [pkgs.turtle])"`.

Comment: this worked for me and also worked for me in 2023 almost 4 years after posting which is pretty impressive as usually the naming for these functions changes yearly.