# Creating a shell.nix file that uses a local nixpkgs and has some extensive configuration

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

can someone help me write a *shell.nix* file for testing my PR

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/194516

The problem is that I can't just install the package as

```bash
nix-env -f "./my-nixpkgs-repo" -iA nixos.fortuneExtensions.blag-fortune
```

This is because it adds the ability to extend fortune-mod based on how pass does
it. I have this code in my normal NixOS configuration:

```hs
user.packages = with pkgs; [
  (pass.withExtensions (exts: [
    exts.pass-otp
    exts.pass-audit
    exts.pass-update
    exts.pass-genphrase
  ]))];
```

I want to do something like this for testing on my branch for the PR, I thought
it would be easiest to develop on if this was done with a shell.nix file, but if
I can do it with just some nix-env command that would also be great

```hs
user.packages = with pkgs; [
  (fortune.withExtensions (exts: [
    exts.blag-fortune
  ]))];
```

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve? Is it to come up with an implementation like `withExtensions`? What is the significance of shell.nix in this case?

Comment: (1/2) I want to have some way to build fortune with some amount of packages in fortuneExtensions without having to specify them in my nixos configuration and wihout having to rebuild the system, and so I can do that from a local nixpkgs and not from the one specified in my nixos configuration. 

A bit like `nix-env -f "/path/to/nixpkgs/repo"` but I also need to install fortune in a way where the extensions are loaded correctly. 

I thought that maybe it was not possible to specify 
```nix user.packages = with pkgs; [
  (fortune.withExtensions (exts: [
    exts.blag-fortune
  ]))];```

Comment: (2/2) with `nix-env` so perhaps I would have to use a `shell.nix` file instead.

Comment: If I understand correctly. Yes you can make a simple nix expression file that would build the same package then (to avoid coupling it with your nixos config). This answer should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378588/1663462

I believe you can just do a nix-shell

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain on the below but I'm guessing you can create a `shell.nix` file like below:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
  (fortune.withExtensions (exts: [
    exts.blag-fortune
  ]))];
}
```

And run `nix-shell` to enter an environment with the above built.

As is the above will error with `error: attribute 'withExtensions' missing` but I assume this is something you've configured else where in your nixos config.